# Deploy Google Cloud Function through Google Build error - unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am unable to deploy a cloud function through google cloud build, receiving the error:

```
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
```

My git repo structure is

```
myrepo/cloudbuild.yaml
myrepo/new-user/index.js
myrepo/new-user/package.json
```

And my cloudbuild.yaml is as follows

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: 'newUser'
  args: ['functions',
  'deploy',
  'newUser',
  '--source=./new-user/.',
  '--trigger-event=providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create',
  '--trigger-resource=projects/myproject/databases/default/documents/userLocations/{user}',
  '--runtime=nodejs8']
```

I thought for cloud functions, only the cloudbuild.yaml is required, which is why the Dockerfile error is confusing.

Running the following on the command line works fine.

```
gcloud functions deploy newUser --runtime=nodejs8 --trigger-event=providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create --trigger-resource=projects/myproject/databases/default/documents/userLocations/{user} --source=./new-user/.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the command you are using to run the Cloud Build itself and also what directory are you in when you run that.  A wild guess I have is that cloudbuild.yaml is not being found and its trying to default to a Docker build.

Comment: I've updated with the gcloud functions deploy command which works fine. I tried without the cloudbuild.yaml file and it fails saying cannot find cloudbuild.yaml, so it's being picked up. Looking in the following blog, it does not mention a Dockerfile is needed also. https://www.toptal.com/devops/better-google-cloud-continuous-deployment

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to initiate a Cloud Build?

Comment: ok sorry. It was setup as a Cloud Build trigger. But the Dockerfile configuration was checked instead of the auto-detect. It works now..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository has no `Dockerfile`, so you cannot use a non-existent `Dockerfile` to build.

Since you are trying to make a serverless container that needs a Docker image as input.

Answer (score 1):

As I just ran into this, the problem for me was linked to the fact that I was working in a monorepo and had to redefine the workspace location Cloud Build would use to find the Dockerfile by adding a `dir` to my cloudbuild file.

My Cloud Build trigger was setup to look for a cloudbuild file that was located under: `<root>/apps/<subfolder>/cloudbuild.yaml`

The cloudbuild file was properly picked up by CloudBuild, the build would start but then errored as the Dockerfile was not found.

YAML example:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-docker-repo/quickstart-image:tag1', '.' ]
images:
- 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-docker-repo/quickstart-image:tag1'
- dir: 'apps/<subfolder>'
```

Reference: [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#dir)